# How to Create Custom Google Streetview Panorama for Android

Tags: android, google-street-view

I am developing an application in which I need to create a feature like Google [Streetview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) with Panorama
But I want to develop my own custom StreetView and render it the same way as the image displayed below:

[image]

and I want to render an images panorama which is offline in my sdcard captured by my Device

I searched lots of sites and even tried this code:

```
   String uri = "google.streetview:cbll=43.082743,-79.078137&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21";
   Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(uri));
   startActivity(streetView);
```

But this is only available online and by using Javascript. Whether I have to use javascript Or Simple Java (Android) & I want to develop this feature offline in android.

If you have any suggestions or possible solutions, it would be appreciated.

Comment: How "custom"? Custom images, custom overlays etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

But the [photo sphere format](https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/) developed by Google used by the default photo sphere [app](http://www.androidcentral.com/get-photosphere-non-nexus-devices-google-edition-camera-app) on Android 4.2+ stock phones was released as an open format.

And Google is strongly encouraging third party developers to make applications that make use of it. Apparently, the code on that site is licensed under Apache 2.0 (but don't ask me if this applies to the meta data itself, I'm not a lawyer).

Here is what a photo sphere [looks like in action](https://google-developers.appspot.com/photo-sphere/web/examples/simple_example) through its special web viewer. Below, you can also see the exact same photo sphere image stored in its native flat format (without the benefit of a photo sphere specific viewer).

[image: flat photo sphere image]

From their android-specific [documentation](https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/android/):

> Applications that wish to handle panoramas of this type should
>   register an **intent filter** for the following MIME type:
>
> **`application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg`**

Furthermore, they seem to indicate they require a geotag for the 360 panorama pictures that they accept from users on Google Maps.

The main limitation being that this viewer application is only available by default on Android 4.2 devices (and thus far, it's only been backported as a separate install from Google Play for Android 4.0+ devices).